# How do you do a Nested if-else statement in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

If I have this function:

```
min(List1, List2, Output) :-
   length(List1, N),
   length(List2, M),
   (   N < M ->
       Output = 'true'
   ;   Output = 'false'
   ).
```

but what if I wanted to also check if N == M? Maybe like this:

```
min(List1, List2, Output) :-
   length(List1, N),
   length(List2, M),
   (   N < M ->
       Output = 'true'
   ;   (  N = M ->
          Output = 'equal'
       ;  Output = 'other'
       )
   ).
```

Doesn't seem to work.

Comment: What, exactly, doesn't seem to work? Are you getting answers you don't expect, or does it not compile?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your nesting of implication (`->`) looks correct here. Note that, in your definition, `N` and `M` will be integers (assuming the calls to `length/2` both succeed), so can be compared with `==` instead of unification (`=`). In fact, you could even use arithmetic equals in SWI-PROLOG, namely, `=:=`:

```
min(List1, List2, Output) :-
    length(List1, N),
    length(List2, M),
    (N < M ->
        Output = 'true'
    ;   (N =:= M ->
            Output = 'equal'
        ;   Output = 'other'
        )
    ).
```

Testing:

```
1 ?- min([a],[b],O).
O = equal.

2 ?- min([a,c],[b],O).
O = other.

3 ?- min([a,c],[b,d],O).
O = equal.

4 ?- min([a,c],[b,d,e],O).
O = true.
```

Comment: (=:=)/2 is an ISO predicate.

Answer (score 4):

In nested if-then-else, it is common to omit redundant parentheses, yielding:

```
min(List1, List2, Output) :-
    length(List1, N),
    length(List2, M),
    (   N < M -> Output = true
    ;   N =:= M -> Output = equal
    ;   Output = other
    ).
```

In Prolog, it is good practice to use *pattern matching* when possible, because this yields more general, more declarative and more readable programs than using if-then-else. For this particular case of conditions, check out the `compare/3` library predicate. `compare/3` lets you reify the relation of the two lengths into an atom, and you can use that atom to describe the three conditions with pattern matching:

```
lists_output(List1, List2, Output) :-
        length(List1, L1),
        length(List2, L2),
        compare(Order, L1, L2),
        order_output(Order, Output).

order_output(<, true).
order_output(=, equal).
order_output(>, other).
```

Sample queries and results:

```
?- lists_output([_,_], [_,_,_], Output).
Output = true.

?- lists_output([_,_,_], [_,_,_], Output).
Output = equal.

?- lists_output([_,_,_,_], [_,_,_], Output).
Output = other.
```

Comment: Quite nice, I like this style, it's neater. I wonder if the operator precedence rules for `->`, `;`, etc. are common amongst other PROLOG implementations such that this isn't SWI-PROLOG specific (probably the case)?

Comment: @Sharky, I don't have an ISO standard ready, but I've seen this style before and @mat's code works perfectly in SICStus 3.12.

Comment: @larsmans: The example uses only ISO's predefined operators. See [tag:iso-prolog] for how to get the standard for USD 30!